# CRichEditCtrl: How to have it scroll to end while focus lost?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have a CRichEditCtrl with auto vertical scrolling set, which works, but not quite as I'd like. The text in the control can be updated via a message from another thread, so it can be busy updating while the user does other things, but the way it updates is different depending on whether it has focus or not (whether or not the caret is blinking). If it has focus, it auto scrolls to the most recent text (at the bottom of the window), without focus you can see the scroll bar shrinking as text is added but there is no actual scroll. Is there any way of getting it to always scroll to the bottom, so that the user always sees what's been most recently added?

I've tried sending EM_SCROLLCARET after ReplaceSel() but it made no difference. Also tried using LineScroll(), but that puts the most recent line at the top of the window, not at the bottom as happens when auto scrolling - this can also result in a blank window if there are trailing new lines ...

Looking on MSDN/forums I can't see much else to try.

Cheers for any help.

Comment: Try using `LineScroll` twice, once to put the last line at the top of the screen, then another to move down by the height of the edit control.

Comment: Thanks. That did cross my mind, but I've no idea how the scroll distance for that height would be worked out. Or is that another question in itself?

Comment: You're right, that would make a good new question. I didn't find it in a quick search. And it can be simplified to just asking how to know how many lines high the control is.

Comment: You can send the control a `WM_VSCROLL` message with `SB_BOTTOM` to go to the end.

Comment: WM_VSCROLL with SB_BOTTOM works exactly as I need, thank you. I figured there must be a straight forward way of doing it.

Comment: @JonathanPotter you should submit that as an answer.